# How to save checkmark in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I'm making a todo app for myself, and i wanted to make a function to mark a todo as done. It adds a checkmark and the font should become grey, but I'm new to coding so i dont really know how to save the font color and the checkmark to memory. I dont know if i sould save it to userdefaults or core data and most importantly how to save it. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code:
I want to save the textColor and accesoryType

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let done = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Done") { (action, view, nil) in
        print("Done")
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
       tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    done.backgroundColor = .blue
    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [done])
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return config           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data model add a property

```
var isDone : Bool = false
```

In `cellForRow` set the UI according to that property (assuming `datasourceArray` is the data source array)

```
let item = datasourceArray[indexPath.row]
cell.textColor = item.isDone ? .lightGray : .blue
cell.accessoryType = item.isDone ? .checkmark : .none
```

In the action set the `isDone` property to `true` and reload the row.

```
let done = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Done") { (action, view, nil) in
    print("Done")
    self.datasourceArray[indexPath.row].isDone = true
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

and delete

```
done.backgroundColor = .blue
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but i dont get the first step. I understand the rest of it, but how do i add the var isDone : Bool = false to the data model?

Comment: The data model is the type in the data source array, preferably a struct or class.

Comment: Ok, so i did that but now is showing an error. "Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'isDone'" in the cell.textColor = item.isDone.

Comment: You have to add `isDone` as Bool attribute in the Core Data entity.

Comment: Depending on the entity code creation settings you might add the `@NSManaged` property manually in the `NSManagedObject` subclass,

Comment: Ok, i dont get that im an idiot. Either way thanks a lot for help man.

Answer (score 0):

You can add todo with var status: Bool ? the store it on database. 
You can setup checkmark with status by setup(status)
Hope help you!